# Insert foreign key records first to avoid racing condition?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have 4 tables.

```
Table1 (primary)
Id

Table2 (foreign 1)
Id
Table1Id

Table3 (foreign 2)
Id
Table1Id
```

Etc

Table1 could have a record without table2,3 and 4 as well.

Now we have many records added to these tables and our application fetches to construct a response based on IDs in Table1.

You would normally add records in Table1 first then table 2 and 3 etc..

Our problem is that our polling (runs every 30seconds) application picks Ids from table1 but fails to get its linked records from Table2,3 and 4 because the application tries to fetch before linked records get saved in table 2,3 and 4 after saving a record in table1.

Is there a way of preventing this? Can we save foreign key records first? This way, the application won't see a record in table1 untill all linked records get saved in table2 and 3? Is it a common and safe practice?

Any advice would be great!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tag the dbms engine you are actually using since any "solution" will likely depend greatly on that fact. Logically, you should be inserting the parent and child rows within a transaction and that should be sufficient to prevent this problem. But I smell the use of nolock - or the absence of a transaction for the "group".

Comment: It sounds like your saving process needs to use transactions (and RCSI). There's not much you can do on the select side except exclude invalid records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your system design you could always have this race condition. For example in a web application if you have a page that allows you to add a TableA, save it, then click a button to enter a related TableB, there is a period of time where a query on TableAs would receive an incomplete representation.

The solution is to either design the system or the data in a way that it can always be counted on to indicate that the data is in a complete state.  For example, instead of designing it so that page-by-page entities in the relationship are saved independently, the user is given the ability to create the entire object graph. Entity Framework works with navigation properties for managing relationships, so if the client-side process walks through capturing the data for a Table A, then related Table B, and C etc. then passing *all* of those details in a structure to be persisted, you can have a single "Save" operation that creates the associated entities all in one go with one call to `SaveChanges`. This ensures all entities are committed together, or not at all. (if there is an exception) EF can take care of ensuring the tables are populated in the right order and assigning the FKs where needed. You don't need to "save" a TableA to get it's ID to populate in the TableB:

```
var tableA = new TableA
{
    Name = viewModel.Name,
    TableB = new TableB
    {
        Name = viewModel.BsName,
        // ... or use biewModel.BDetails.Name, etc.
    },
    TableC = new TableC
    {
        // ....
    }
};

context.TableAs.Add(tableA);
context.SaveChanges();  // Saves the A, B, and related C, etc.
```

If the data is rather large and complex and it doesn't make sense to try and capture everything at once, for instance if the data might be entered over a significant span of time given the user has to accumulate or check data etc. before the record state is considered complete enough to be queried on, then you can consider using something like a Status on your top level table. (TableA) This could be something like an enumeration. When you create your TableA record initially, the status would be defaulted to something like "InProgress". Any query reporting or such looking at TableAs would know only to query records with a Status of "Complete". As the user enters their Table B, C, etc. there would be either an automatic validation or manual assertion to determine if the TableA record can be marked off as "Complete", updating the status. From that point the report/summary query views would start seeing that row in results.